# Building PreparedStatement in Java With Variable Number of Columns for Inserting Data into Database

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

What is a good design pattern to achieve this without endless code?

Given the scenario whereby the user may input 1...100 columns, maybe 23 one time, 32 on another insert, and 99 fields on another insert etc. All of which may be different fields each time too.

The PreparedStatement in Java needs to know what `column names` to enter first, how many `?`'s to put into the values part of the `INSERT` query, the data types of the database field names to ensure the correct `setInt` and `setString` etc are entered.

For less than around 10 columns, you can kind of get around this challenge with the following logic;

1) If variableEnteredForFieldName is not null, then append to the relevant parts of the query in the form of a String builder type setup;

```
fieldName_1

?
```

2) Do the same for all entered field names

3) Strip out the final trailing `,` that will naturally be present in both the `field names` and the `?`s

4) Create the PreparedStatement

5) Run through the same input parameters again to determine of the variableEnteredForFieldName is not null, if not null, then run a setInt or setString based on the known data type that the database requires and set this to the correct index number for the ?s.

As long as the query builder logic and the query filler logic have the names/values in the correct order in part 1 and part 2, then all works well. It does however mean duplicating the entire code that relates to this logic, one for generating the SQL to use when creating the PreparedStatement and another for filling the PreparedStatement.

This is manageable for a small number of input parameters, but this soon gets unmanageable for larger number of input parameters.

Is there a better design pattern to achieve the same logic?

The code below is an outline of all of the above for reference;

```
String fieldName1 = request.getParameter("fieldName1");
    String fieldName2 = request.getParameter("fieldName2");

    //Build Query
    String fieldNames = "";
    String fieldQuestionMarks = "";

    if (fieldName1 != null) {
        fieldNames = fieldNames + " FIELD_NAME_1 ,";
        fieldQuestionMarks = fieldQuestionMarks + " ? ,";
    }

    if (fieldName2 != null) {
        fieldNames = fieldNames + " FIELD_NAME_2 ,";
        fieldQuestionMarks = fieldQuestionMarks + " ? ,";
    }

//Trim the trailing ,
    fieldNames = fieldNames.substring(1, fieldNames.length() - 1);
    fieldQuestionMarks = fieldQuestionMarks.substring(1, fieldQuestionMarks.length() - 1);


    try {
        String completeCreateQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME ( " + fieldNames + " ) VALUES ( " + fieldQuestionMarks + " );";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, user, password);
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(completeCreateQuery);

        int parameterIndex = 1;

        //Fill Query
        if (fieldName1 != null) {
            preparedStatement.setString(parameterIndex, fieldName1);
            parameterIndex++;
        }

        if (fieldName2 != null) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(parameterIndex, Integer.parseInt(fieldName2));
            parameterIndex++;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it's do-able. But even with just 2 optional fields, this code is huge.

Comment: It's "huge" unless you use loops instead of hardcoding every field. This may involve putting the field names and values into a `Map` data structure.

Comment: Correct. But with a Map being a key/value store this does not take into account the data type of the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, if user is able to omit any of the columns from the list, then all columns are optional, and can be safely set to NULL during an insert. Therefore, all you need is one prepared statement with the "monster" INSERT, with all columns listed; then during the actual insert operation, you loop though the user-provided data, setting values for the columns provided, and calling `setNull()` for omitted columns. You'll need to maintain a structure somewhere (your DAO class most likely) mapping column names to their order in the SQL statement.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: explain the downvote please. The way I see it, neither the linked questiong have actually proposed a viable solution (dynamically-built INSERT list, seriously?), nor was my suggestion actually proposed there

Comment: I also wondered why this answer was down voted so quickly. For my this is the perfect solution that you have provided Alex. This was I can simply create said monster INSERT statement, and if the data has not been entered for this parameter by the user, I can simply use the setNull() option that you mention. I wasn't aware of that function. Thanks.